# pointer to 2d array

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code:

```
int arr[2][2][2]={10,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int *p;
printf("%u",arr);
p=(int *)arr;
printf("%u",p);
```

Which outputs

```
64166
64164
```

But I would think that `p` and `arr` point to the same memory address. Why are different addresses shown?

Comment: The first printout prints an uninitialized value.

Comment: I ran the the same piece of code, the result is : 3216608828,3216608828 !

Comment: thnks for clearing the doubt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But same code

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {

         int arr[2][2][2]={10,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
         int *p;
         printf("\n%u",arr);
         p=(int *)arr;
         printf("\n%u\n",p);
         return 0;
    }
```

gives same result only.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's walk through the code

```
 int *p;
 printf("%u",p);
```

p is an unitialized int pointer.  It is going to print out whatever is in memory.

```
 p=(int *)arr;
 printf("%u",p);
```

p now is pointing to the address of the array in memory, and prints that address.

Comment: oh sorry,i made a mistake in the code...  the first printf is printf("%u",arr) and since arr and p point to same value then why does the second printf show diff values...

Comment: Are you trying to print out *values* from the array?

Comment: Adding to this, `%u` is for printing an `unsigned int`, `%p` prints a pointer.

Comment: I m just trying to figure out the logic behind this.i dont want to print out values from array.